# Excel VBA Select and copy number of rows based on dynamic cell value in a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In sheet 1, in Cell C3, numeric values keep changing. I want the number of rows in Sheet2 to be selected based on the cell value C3 in sheet 1. For example, Sheet2 has 100 rows and 7 columns. In sheet1, If C2=X and C3=5, I want vba to loop through sheet2 column A to find the first matching cell for X, and then select the C3 number of rows from the first match, and copy them to sheet3.

```
                  Sheet1   Sheet2  Sheet3 (final result)
                  C2=X     A1=a    A3 row
                  C3=5     A2=b    A4 row
                           A3=X    A5 row
                           A4=X    A6 row
                           A5=X    A7 row
                           A6=X
                           A7=X
                           A8=X
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    a = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    b = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a
        For j = 2 To b
            If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value > Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 5).Value Then
                    'THE CODE I NEED HELP WITH
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can use ".resize". This method belongs to a selection object and the arguments I think are #rows, #columns. Try playing with that.

Comment: I am basically looking for a code where the number of rows selected and copied depends on a cell value..for example, if a cell value C3=5, i want 5 rows selected, if C3=9, I want 9 rows selected.

Comment: How do I pass a cell value as argument in Range or Cell functions?

Comment: something like cell.value